# Install Aptana twig plugin

Tags: eclipse, twig, aptana

I cant install twig on Aptana 3.5 (latest). 
Someone got it working?

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Twig Editor Feature 1.0.13.201309142024 (com.dubture.twig.feature.feature.group 1.0.13.201309142024)
  Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.5.0.201401092130-09012014213131 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.5.0.201401092130-09012014213131)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 50.1.1.v201304230130 (com.ibm.icu 50.1.1.v201304230130)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.4.2.v20110823 (com.ibm.icu 4.4.2.v20110823)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.0.1.v20090822 (com.ibm.icu 4.0.1.v20090822)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.0.1.v20090415 (com.ibm.icu 4.0.1.v20090415)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 RCP 3.5.0.201401092130-7q7dFA-FEB7f0RnEDkUtiuDg8D48 (com.aptana.feature.rcp.feature.group 3.5.0.201401092130-7q7dFA-FEB7f0RnEDkUtiuDg8D48)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.3.1.v20130911-1000]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 3.5.0.201401092130-09012014213131 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.5.0.201401092130-09012014213131)
    To: com.aptana.feature.rcp.feature.group [3.5.0.201401092130-7q7dFA-FEB7f0RnEDkUtiuDg8D48]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Twig Editor Feature 1.0.13.201309142024 (com.dubture.twig.feature.feature.group 1.0.13.201309142024)
    To: com.dubture.twig.ui [1.0.13.201309142024]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Twig UI Plugin 1.0.13.201309142024 (com.dubture.twig.ui 1.0.13.201309142024)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.php.ui 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse e4 Rich Client Platform 1.2.1.v20130910-2014 (org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group 1.2.1.v20130910-2014)
    To: com.ibm.icu [50.1.1.v201304230130]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PDT UI Plug-in 2.1.1.v20090914-1400 (org.eclipse.php.ui 2.1.1.v20090914-1400)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.web 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PDT UI Plug-in 2.1.1.v20090921-1100 (org.eclipse.php.ui 2.1.1.v20090921-1100)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.web 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PDT UI Plug-in 3.2.0.201401101713 (org.eclipse.php.ui 3.2.0.201401101713)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.web 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.3.1.v20130911-1000 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.3.1.v20130911-1000)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.3.1.v20130911-1000]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 4.3.1.v20130911-1000 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.3.1.v20130911-1000)
    To: org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group [1.2.1.v20130910-2014]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Simple Web Plug-in 1.1.301.v200909021400 (org.eclipse.wst.web 1.1.301.v200909021400)
    To: bundle com.ibm.icu [3.4.4,4.1.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Simple Web Plug-in 1.1.301.v200911302230 (org.eclipse.wst.web 1.1.301.v200911302230)
    To: bundle com.ibm.icu [3.4.4,4.1.0)
```

Comment: Needed to add lorem ipsum, i could not post without cuz stackoverflow says too much code, too less text...

Comment: I removed lorem ipsum.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex one. There is some sort of incompatibility between the versions of software you are trying to install.  I'm guessing that twig is not compatible with the latest version of Aptana.  See if you can get a more recent version of twig (even try a development build).